# Shiny: data.frame conditional format

Tags: r, format, shiny, dt

I have a Shiny application and I want to create a tableOutput using the following data.frame:

```
data <- data.frame(X=c('A','B','C','D'),Y=c(1,5,7,3))
```

In the app, there is a numericInput named input$sign and I would like to make **bold** the cells of the column Y if the value is smaller than that input.

I've tried using a datatable object, but it doesn't appear in the application and I don't know why. I've created it with the following code:

```
data <- datatable(data, options=list(searching=F, paging=F,autoWidth = T)) %>% 
            formatStyle("Y", fontWeight = styleInterval(input$sign,c('bold', 'weight')))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where you have problems but see working example

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data <- data.frame(X=c('A','B','C','D'),Y=c(1,5,7,3))
server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$tt=DT::renderDataTable(
    datatable(data, options=list(searching=F, paging=F,scrollX = T)) %>% 
      formatStyle("Y", fontWeight = styleInterval(input$sign,c('bold', 'weight')))

  )

})

ui=shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    numericInput("sign","sign",0),
    DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```